# MySQL, recover database after mysqlbinlog loading error?

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

I am copying a MySQL DB from an initial dump file and the set of binlogs created after the dump.

The initial load from the dump is fine. Then, while loading the binlogs using mysqlbinlog, what happens is that one of the files will fail, for example, with a "server has gone away" error.

Is there any way to recover from a failed mysqlbinlog run, or is the database copy now irreparably corrupted? I know which log has failed, but I can't just rerun that log since the error could have occurred at any query within the log.

Is there a way to handle this moving forward?

I can look into minimizing the chances that there will be an error in the first place, but it doesn't seem like much of a recovery process (or master/slave process) if any MySQL issue during the loading completely ruins the database. I feel that I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check the configuration value for `max_allowed_packet`. This is pretty small by default (4MB or 64MB depending on MySQL version). You might need to increase it.

Note that you need to increase that option both in the server and in the client that is applying binlogs. The effective limit on packet size is the *lesser* of the server and client's configuration value.

Even if the binlog succeeded through replication, it might not succeed when replaying binlogs, because you need to replay with `mysql` while specifying  the `--max-allowed-packet` option.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html for more explanation of the error you got.

---

If you don't know the binlog coordinates of the last binlog event that succeeded, you'll have to start over: remove the partially-restored instance and restore from the backup again, then apply the binlog.

Comment: max_allowed_client is higher on the replication MySQL than on the original. If the packet size wasn't too large when the query was originally run, shouldn't it be good enough now? (I'm going from MySQL 5.6 to 5.7 if that matters.) Also, this doesn't answer the question of how to continue from the error, without recreating the complete database again (loading a 150 GB dump and then the binlogs).

Comment: Updated my answer above.

Comment: OK, you are so right. I checked the mysql log (not just the error that mysqlbinlog prints out) and it actually says "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes" Step 1: read all the logs. Thanks!